# RelatedTo query with length criteria

Tags: relations, queries, relatedto, query

I am trying to get results from a relatedTo query, but only if there are more than say 1 results. Right now I am using two queries to achieve this, like so:

```
{% set authors = craft.entries({
    section: 'authors',
    with: [
        'authorImage',
    ],
    limit: 18,
    order: 'authorSurname asc'
}) %}
{% for author in authors %}
    {% set relatedEntries = craft.entries.section('articles').sponsoredAuthor('= 0').relatedTo(author) %}
    {% if relatedEntries|length > 1 %} ... {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But this messes up pagination (amongst other things) because the loop will iterate no mater if the related entries have more than 1 result. So I was wondering if it is possible (without using a custom query) to have the same result as a single query, so that the results match the number of the items in the loop and pagination does not break. Something like:

```
authors = craft.entries.section('authors').relatedTo('articles where articles results > 1)
```

or something like that. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the relationship field stored on the Authors or the Entries? What is its handle?

Comment: Hi Brandon, the relationship field is stored on the entries (relatedAuthor). Tried something like that `relatedTo({
    sourceElement: craft.entries.section('articles').sponsoredAuthor('= 1'),
    field: 'relatedAuthor'` but still not sure how to get the length / results from Articles

Comment: OK and to clarify, you want to loop through all the authors that have at least 2 entries related to them?

Comment: Exactly! But on a single query, otherwise if I have to add a condition whether or not to show something (relatedEntries > 1) it messes up the pagination. I am also looking for a sponsoredAuthor (a field on articles) to be off (0) - here is our demo http://www.epixeiro.gr/authors, you can see many authors with 0 or 1 entries - I do not want to show these, but I still want the pagination (limit + offset entries) to work properly! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think to do this is with a plugin that tracks the relation count, storing it as a custom field.

First create a new Number custom field called “Total Articles” (handle: `totalArticles`). Assign it to your Authors field layout.

Then create a new [plugin](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/introduction). Put this in the primary plugin class’ `init()` method:

```php
craft()->on('entries.saveEntry', function(Event $event) {
    /** @var EntryModel $entry */
    $entry = $event->params['entry'];

    if ($entry->getSection()->handle === 'articles') {
        // Update author relation counts
        foreach ($entry->relatedAuthor as $author) {
            $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
            $criteria->section = 'articles';
            $criteria->relatedTo(array(
                'targetElement' => $author,
                'field' => 'relatedAuthor'
            ));
            $totalArticles = $criteria->total();

            craft()->db->createCommand()->update('content',
                array('field_totalArticles' => $totalArticles),
                array('elementId' => $author->id));
        }
});
```

Finally, from your template, you can fetch only the authors that have at least 2 articles like so:

```twig
{% set authors = craft.entries({
    section: 'authors',
    totalArticles: '>= 2',
    with: [
        'authorImage',
    ],
    limit: 18,
    order: 'authorSurname asc'
}) %}
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon! It works, just had to change $criteria->relatedTo = array(...); But now I have to re-save all entries in order to get the proper counts. Is there a (mass) way to do this, without updating the "updated date"? Thanks!

Comment: @epap If you resave the section, all the entries will get resaved (even if you don't change any settings). Although I think that the dateUpdated columns will get updated, too.

Comment: What if I want to remove an author from an article. How to I update the totalArticles textfield. I cannot find an event that will help me grab the previous author (related entry) before I replace it (or remove it) - How do I approach this?